# Conveniently downloading all the files in a CloudDirectory

Tags: files-and-directories, wolfram-cloud

Working on a data viz project online, I created a cloud directory with hundreds of plots I'd like to now download for final processing and visualization. Realistically, I'd just like to be able to right click and download the whole folder on the portal but that doesn't appear to be an option.

I've been working for hours today trying to get either `CopyFile` or `CreateArchive` to work with no results yet. Favouring the simpler approach at this point, I'd be happy if `CreateArchive` just took all the PNG files in the directory and compressed them into a zip in the same directory for download.

I tried the following code after setting the `CloudDirectory` to the path with all the PNGs in it with `SetCloudDirectory`, however it's just returned back to me without executing. The behaviour is not following some of the examples I found on stack-exchange or in the docs.

```
test = CloudDirectory[];
CreateArchive[test, "test.zip"]
```

returns:

```
CreateArchive[CloudObject[https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/user/Projects/05%20Seismic%20Project/posterframes],test.zip]
```

Judging from the docs page, it should return the path of the new archive file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how you can do this. Go on the web interface, make the `ZIP` there, then copy it to a `CloudObject`. E.g.:

```
meep=CreateArchive[Directory[]<>"/author", "test.zip"];
CopyFile[meep, CloudObject["test.zip"]]
```

You may want to change up the permissions, like `CloudObject["test.zip", Permissions->"Public"]`

Clicking on the link to that `CloudObject` will now download the ZIP

Comment: I can't get this approach to work sadly. I'm failing right at step one `Directory[]<>"/author"`. I tried all sorts of combinations of URLs and strings, and it failed every time to find the directory the plots were in. Could this be a problem with the Wolfram cloud perhaps?

Comment: I used `Directory[]/author` just because I had less in it. You should use whichever directory is pertinent to you.

Comment: Yeah I tried two main approaches (with variations). A full string path similar to the one I used to export all the plots to the directory in the first place. And secondly, the set `CloudDirectory`. Both failed. I'm just wondering why I can reproduce this. I exported to this path in the notebook.`"https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/user/Projects/05%20Seismic%20Project/posterframes`

Comment: You can see what directories you have by evaluating `FileNames["*", Directory[]]` in the cloud interface

Comment: Unfortunately `Directory[]` on the cloud doesn't give the same behaviour as Desktop Mathematica. `CloudDirectory[]` does not seem to work with `CreateArchive`. It will always fail with the "file or directory not found". This behaviour changes how `FileNames` works too. Pointed at the full directory of plotted PNGs it files nothing.

Comment: `Directory` works fine for me in the cloud interface...maybe things aren’t where you expect them to be? What are you trying exactly?

Comment: `NotebookDirectory[]` got the `CreateArchive` & `Filenames` to work. But now it's not showing up in the browser though it's there when I use Filenames. Getting closer.

Comment: Use `CopyFile` to a `CloudObject` after making the archive. That’s what I did, if you notice.

Comment: Excellent.. That did the trick. It didn't export the files with the ".png" but I can fix that if I run it again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CopyDirectory`.

```
In[11]:= CloudObjects["test", All]

Out[11]= {CloudObject[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/damanjits/test/destDir"], \
CloudObject[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/damanjits/test/myDesktopFile.nb"], \
CloudObject[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/damanjits/test/myNewAPI"], \
CloudObject[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/damanjits/test/namedObj"], \
CloudObject[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/damanjits/test/obj"], CloudObject[
 "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/damanjits/test/provoceBug"]}

In[7]:= CopyDirectory[CloudObject["test"], "/tmp/cloudTestDir"]

Out[7]= "/tmp/cloudTestDir"

In[12]:= FileNames[All, "/tmp/cloudTestDir", Infinity] // Column

Out[12]= 
/tmp/cloudTestDir/destDir
/tmp/cloudTestDir/destDir/conflower.jpg
/tmp/cloudTestDir/myDesktopFile.nb
/tmp/cloudTestDir/myNewAPI
/tmp/cloudTestDir/namedObj
/tmp/cloudTestDir/obj
/tmp/cloudTestDir/provoceBug
```

We will add this usage in ref/CopyDirectory. Thank You.

Comment: This would work if I had a desktop kernel to work with. Alas.. I'm cloud only for the moment. Is there an alternative to this? I know this is an edge case perhaps but there's mathematicians everywhere.